# IONIC - IOS screen doesn’t resize when changing landscape to portrait

Tags: ionic-framework

i'm struggling with this problem and i hope someone can help me.

When i start the app, it's normal until i change the orientation from landscape from portrait. The screen doesn't resize and the height and width still on landscape sizes no matter what.

I can't put some examples from screens shot.

I already tried to fix it with css, changing a lot meta tag, trying to do $ionicScrollDelegate.resize() onchangeorientation envent and other events but nothing works...

I hope i can get some help. Thanks!

Comment: How means "doesn't resize"? Please show us a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

i took out the meta tag and somehow it works...